# Generate JSON payload based on JSON schema for API payload validation

Tags: json

I am looking for a way to generate random payloads in JSON based on the provided schema. Looking around I found something useful but with not a lot of github stars. [LINK](https://github.com/yaronassa/SchemaPayloadGenerator#readme)

**Objective**

To be able to validate multiple possible values for a field in the payload based on the schema provided.

**Example**

For schema  -

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "name"
  ]
}
```

Possible payloads -

```
{
  "name": "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZA"
}

{
  "name": "ERTERER"
}
```

I hope my request for suggestion was clear.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I have tried json generators like https://www.liquid-technologies.com , https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-from-schema etc.. but none that's a reliable solution.

Comment: Have you tried implementing it yourself